# How to create own custom controls / templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have to create different worksheets for my class at school. 
`Questions and answer lines` or `Question and checkboxes`. Now could I create this kind of sheet everytime on my own, but I want to have some kind of custom controls.

That I can simple **Insert -> CustomControl1**. Is this posible?

[image: preview]

#### Solution

Based on *cnread* comment, you have to use `QuickParts`. You find a tutorial here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Quick-Parts-and-AutoText-in-Word-7a527697-058f-4967-b8f1-aae0774e4813

[image: solution preview]

Comment: Will the worksheets be filled in online/in Word, or will you print them and have students fill them in with a pen/pencil? In other words, do they have to be interactive? If not, you probably don't have to use controls at all and can just create a template document in which you create one generic question of each type, select it, and save it as a Quick Part. Then, to create an actual worksheet, for each question, insert a copy of the relevant Quick Part, and update the text of it and the text for each check box.

Comment: Great! I have always overlooked this function. In combination with `Repeating Section Content Control` is this amazing and exactly what I wanted!